# Integeration twilio client phonegap application ( Platform Phonegap )

Tags: javascript, cordova, twilio, phonegap-plugins, phonegap

I am working on the PhoneGap application for the Twilio client to make calls from a mobile.

I have followed the plugin guide from the below link.

> https://github.com/jefflinwood/twilio_client_phonegap

I have done so far as per the instructions.
Got the token from my server-side for initializing the Twilio.
There is one js library **tcPlugin** they are using. I have placed it as well.

Now when I serve PhoneGap and run the app on browser no errors are there except one which is

> Error: exec proxy not found for :: TCPlugin :: deviceSetup

and when I hit to make a call it's giving me the error

> Error: exec proxy not found for :: TCPlugin :: connect

I have googled these things but found nothing.

Is anyone there who can help me out with this proxy issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I have not worked with this Cordova plugin. However, you say you are trying to run it in the browser. Checking the [source code](https://github.com/jefflinwood/twilio_client_phonegap) it seems that there is code available for the iOS and Android platforms, but nothing to support a browser. Googling for the error "exec proxy not found for" shows up other people with issues running Cordova plugins in the browser.

Have you tried running this in a simulator?

If you need to run this in a browser I recommend raising an issue on the [plugin repo](https://github.com/jefflinwood/twilio_client_phonegap).

Comment: Thanks @philnash for your response. It worked when I created the build and ran on live. It does not support browser.
Thanks again

Comment: Glad that makes sense at least. Since this was the right answer, would you mind accepting it so that others can see it helped? Thanks!